# Is there a place for thinking problems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Somewhere I can put thinking problems? If you don't know what I mean by that, an example is [Einstein's Riddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle). I'm not asking a place to put riddles or math problems, rather to put long problems (that are most words) that can be put in an Computer Science Olympiad for example. Not actually coding, rather logical and algorithmic problems.

I hope you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).  Incidentally, there are the posts [Einstein's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16109/einsteins-puzzle) and [Fast strategies for solving Einstein's puzzles?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78/fast-strategies-for-solving-einsteins-puzzles) from that site.

There is also [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and its [puzzle tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle).  The [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there says that "Solving mathematical puzzles." is on topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). From their site description:

> Puzzling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those who create, solve, and study puzzles.